# ASP .NET MVC 4 IValidatableObject calling frequency/timing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to understand the communication between client and server within the context of an IValidatableObject.

I have a ViewModel with one of the properties, `CompanyId`, decorated with `[Remote("ValidateCompanyId", "Home")]`.

In my "Home" controller, of course, I have the ValidateCompanyId action.

The view has a textbox for CompanyId.  When the view is first displayed, I can type as much as I want into the text box and there is no interaction with the server.  When the text box loses focus, the ValidateCompanyId action is called.  If the validation fails, I get my error message back in the view.  So far, so good.

At this point, however, each subsequent keystroke makes a call to the server.  For example, if I originally typed 8500 and got an error, if I want to change my value to 8200, I am seeing server calls for 850, then 85, then 8, then 82, then 820, then, finally, 8200.

I think I would prefer that the validation call wait for the text box to lose focus again (as it does at first).  Particularly, in this case, because the validation requires a database call.  What controls this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default behavior. Before a field is marked as invalid, validation is lazy allowing you to tab through controls, but once its marked as invalid, it is eagerly validated ([Refer documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)). You can prevent validation on `keyup` using the following script

```
var validator = $("form").data("validator");
if (validator) {
  validator.settings.onkeyup = false;
}
```

Note this disables `keyup` validation for all controls. If you want it for only one control try (not tested)

```
$(yourSelector).keyup(function() { return false } );
```

Comment: I tested both of these approaches, and they both worked.